# Why FindBoost.cmake always read the old BOOST_ROOT, which no longer exist, no longer in any files which store env variables

Tags: boost, cmake

I do not know if this is a environment variable issue, or a `FindBoost.cmake` issue. For the env variable part, I set the `BOOST_ROOT` to `/usr/include` in `~/.bashrc` already. And I have checked `~/.bash_profile`, `~/.bash_login`, `~/.profile`, `/etc/profile`, `/etc/bash.bashrc`, and`/etc/environment` to make sure `BOOST_ROOT` is not set elsewhere.

I have `cmake3.5.1-1ubuntu3` and `libboost-all-dev(1.58.0.1ubuntu1)` installed. I have before `boost1.55.0` from source, which I have deleted from the directory `/usr/local/boost_1_55_0` already. But, the `FindBoost.cmake` always said that:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.5/Modules/FindBoost.cmake:1073 (file):
  file STRINGS file "/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/boost/version.hpp" cannot be
  read.
```

I have basically checked every places where can store environment variables, and there is no `/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/boost/version.hpp`, but why  does this `/usr/local/boost_1_55_0/boost/version.hpp` still exist? Where is it?

---

This is the original question, which I have already figure out.

I installed the `'libboost-all-dev'` package, and I found out that, all these libaries are `.a` or `.so` files, only these following have header files:

```
./usr/include/boost/fusion/include/boost_tuple.hpp
./usr/include/boost/fusion/include/boost_array.hpp
./usr/include/boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple/boost_tuple_iterator.hpp
./usr/include/boost/fusion/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp
./usr/include/boost/fusion/adapted/boost_array.hpp
./usr/include/boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_fusion.hpp
./usr/include/boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_tuple.hpp
./usr/include/boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_array.hpp
./usr/include/boost/geometry/geometries/adapted/boost_polygon.hpp
./usr/include/boost/icl/detail/boost_config.hpp
```

all the other static and shared libaries are in `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` and `/usr/share/lintian/overrides/`. There is no `version.hpp`. But the `FindBoost.cmake` has exactly the following line:

```
file(STRINGS "${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR}/boost/version.hpp" _boost_VERSION_HPP_CONTENTS REGEX "#define BOOST_(LIB_)?VERSION ")
```

So what should I do about it?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: The package `libboost-all-dev` depends from `libboost1.67-dev` one, which [contains](https://packages.ubuntu.com/disco/amd64/libboost1.67-dev/filelist) file `/usr/include/boost/version.hpp`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Hi, Thanks for your help! But I set my `BOOST_ROOT` to `/usr/include`, but the FindBoost.cmake always said that: `Boost include path: /usr/local/boost_1_55_0`. I checked out the places where stores environment variables, `.bashrc, .profile, /etc/profile, /etc/bash.bashrc, or /etc/environment` , and there is no such `BOOST_ROOT` set to `/usr/local/boost_1_55_0`. What can I do now?

Comment: Have you cleared build directory (the directory where you run `cmake`) after changing Boost settings? `/usr/include` is an **include directory**, it cannot be the root of any package including the Boost. `BOOST_ROOT` could be `/usr` directory for example. Show (add to the question post) the **exact configuration messages** about the Boost when you run `cmake` with option `-DBoost_DEBUG=ON`.

Comment: @Tsyvarev Thank you so much for reminding me of clearing build directory!! That is the problem..I cannot believe I spent one week stucking at this.